# downloadUrl give empty result

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I have a function to upload some data to firebase like this

```
private fun addDatatoFirebase(){
    val addImage = StorageRef.child(preferences.getValue("username").toString()).child("food_pics/"+UUID.randomUUID())
    addImage.putFile(FilePath).addOnSuccessListener {
        addImage.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
            PicUrl = it.toString()
        }
    }


    val dataRef = ref.child(preferences.getValue("username").toString()).child("FoodList/"+UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        dataRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                id = snapshot.ref
                Log.w("PicUrl data",PicUrl)
                dataRef.child("image_pic").setValue(PicUrl)
                dataRef.child("name").setValue(food_name)
                dataRef.child("avail").setValue(availability)
                dataRef.child("price").setValue(food_price.toInt())
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)                }

        })
}
```

It has a problem that **PicUrl** is empty eventhough i already give it value here :

```
addImage.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                PicUrl = it.toString()
            }
```

The log shows that PicUrl Value is "", since i initialize the var with PicUrl = ""
here is the log :

```
W/PicUrl data: 
W/PicUrl data:
```

So now, i wonder what is wrong with my code in that function that create such error

Comment: Have you tried to add the read operation inside onSuccess? This is because Firebase API is asynchronous.

Comment: try adding a log in `addOnSuccessListener ` chances are that it comes there after the other log statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Comment: @AlexMamo I think i did, but there still no change on the result

Comment: @IvoBeckers well weirdly, i added log inside addImage.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener and the log doesn't showed up. does my code skipping it?

Comment: Please edit your question with the changed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
addImage.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                PicUrl = it.toString()
                dataRef.child("image_pic").setValue(PicUrl)
            }
```

Since downloadUrl is asynchronous. I need to include the code that need the value of it inside the callback which means putting :

```
dataRef.child("image_pic").setValue(PicUrl)
```

inside addOnSuccessListener